# PayPal API to access trasactional data

Tags: paypal

I would like to extract transaction data from my customer's PayPal account. He has given me the API username, p/w, and signature. In addition, we created a live 'application' on developer.paypal.com so now I have a ClientID and Secret.

I have the asp.net/c# RestAPiSample code. Which (REST or SOAP) API(s) should I call to get "sales" data (i.e., payments from his customers to his paypal account? Basically I am trying to create some additional reports using the sales data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your customer's paypal account credentials can be used with Merchant SDK. You can use the API 'getTransactionDetails' to fetch his customers sales records.

But the new live account you have created (ClientID and ClientSecret) can only be used with the new REST APIs and its is not related to your customers account. If you want your customers sales records you can use the Payment.List(...) method which returns a PaymentHistory object.